# Prevent parent swipe event if there exists child swipe event

Tags: javascript, touch, hammer.js

I'm using Hammer.js and have a swipe/touch event on a site container element, this event displays a menu. The problem is that sometimes there are child elements to the container that also listen to this event, and then both events are called.

I want to prevent the menu event if the swipe occurs on a slideshow (flexslider) or other child objects that listen to touch events.

Is it possible?

I want to avoid changing the code for the child elements if possible.

Comment: You can use `stopPropagation`. Check this: https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Event-delegation-and-how-to-stopPropagation---preventDefaults

Comment: So the only way is to add stopPropagation for all child elements if they listen to the same event? For example I don't want to add this to the events in the flexslider plugin file.

Comment: How are you binding the events to child elements?